# Simplifying code that are identical funs except for the signature (varargs vs map)

Tags: kotlin

I have some very very similar code and I was wondering if there was a way to simplify it?

```
fun parametersOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, Any>): Parameters {

    val p = Parameters(pairs.size)

    for ((key, value) in pairs)
        when (value) {
            is String  -> p.put(key, value)
            is Int     -> p.put(key, value)
            is Double  -> p.put(key, value)
            is Boolean -> p.put(key, value)
            else -> throw BBIllegalOperationException("Unknown type for value:'$value' of key:'$key'")
        }

    return p
}

fun parametersOf(map: Map<String, Any>): Parameters {
    val p = Parameters(map.size)

    for ((key, value) in map)
        when (value) {
            is String  -> p.put(key, value)
            is Int     -> p.put(key, value)
            is Double  -> p.put(key, value)
            is Boolean -> p.put(key, value)
            else -> throw BBIllegalOperationException("Unknown type for value:'$value' of key:'$key'")
        }

    return p
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave one of the functions as it is and make the other call it, in either way:

```
fun parametersOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, Any>) = 
    parametersOf(pairs.toMap())
```

Or, using the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) to call the `vararg` function:

```
fun parametersOf(map: Map<String, Any>): Parameters = 
    parametersOf(*map.toList().toTypedArray())
```

Also, if the `p.put(key, value)` lines all call the same function accepting `Any` (not different ones for `String`, `Int`, `Double` and `Boolean`, due to the smart casts), you can replace the four `when` branches with one:

```
when (value) {
    is String, is Int, is Double, is Boolean -> p.put(key, value)
    else -> throw BBIllegalOperationException("...")
}
```

Comment: `put` is overloaded java code in this particular situation.